# How to add custom bar labels to ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm a new R user and I'm trying to add custom labels to my bar graph using ggplot2. These labels are not part of my data set and I used stat="summary" instead of "identity", so I'm getting confused on how to properly implement geom_text.

Each bar represents a different treatment (treatment 1, treatment 2, etc). I want bar 1 to be labeled "ab",  bar 2 as "ac", bar 3 as "c", bar 4 as "a", and bar 5 as "bc". I have a list called "summary" which contains these labels in the column "sig_labels." I then attempted to apply the labels using geom_text without success.

Thanks so much for your help!

My dataset looks like this:

```
Treatment       Speed
 1  Treatment 1      3
 2  Treatment 1      4
 3  Treatment 1      3.4
 4  Treatment 1      3.3
 5  Treatment 2      2
 6  Treatment 2      3.3
 7  Treatment 2      2.8
 8  Treatment 2      3.1
 9  Treatment 3      4.4
 10 Treatment 3      4.3
 11 Treatment 3      5
 12 Treatment 3      3.9
 13 Treatment 4      4.2
 14 Treatment 4      2.2
 15 Treatment 4      2.1
 16 Treatment 4      2.1
 17 Treatment 5      3.0
 18 Treatment 5      3.2
 19 Treatment 5      3.3
 20 Treatment 5      3.4
```

while my summary list looks like this:

```
Treatment        sig_labels
 1   Treatment 1       ab
 2   Treatment 2       ac
 3   Treatment 3       c
 4   Treatment 4       a
 5   Treatment 5       bc
```

and my code looks like this:

```
dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Treatment, y= Speed)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y= "mean", fill="#FAA756", width= 0.5, colour="black", 
           size = 0.3) +
  ggtitle("Speed") +
  xlab("Treatment") + 
  ylab("Speed") +
  stat_summary(fun.data= mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = .2, size = 0.3) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
    text = element_text(family = "Calibri"),
   # Remove panel border
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    # Remove panel grid lines
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    # Remove panel background
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    # Add axis line
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,5.5))
```

+
  geom_text(data=summary, aes(label = sig_labels, vjust = -0.2))

Comment: I think there are packages for easy labeling of ggplots with significance annotations. `ggpubr` I think is one. But there are others as well.

Comment: Some links: ggsignif: https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/blob/master/README.md. ggpubr: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/

Comment: It looks like you are missing a column in the `summary` dataset that indicates where on the y axis the labels should be placed (maybe mean `Speed`?).  Another option is to calculate the means and error bars outside ggplot and then add the labels to that; then all layers would be made from the same dataset.

Comment: Thanks so much- adding the y axis location fixed it! So now it is: 
`geom_text(data=summary, aes(label = sig_labels, y= mean_speed + .3)`